On the definite integral $\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{1}e^{-\ln^2\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)}dx$
On a problem I'm working on, I've come across this integral: $$I=\int_{-1}^{1}e^{-\ln^2\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)}dx$$
and I'm wondering how to evaluate it analytically. I don't think the context would be much help.
A simple substitution $u=\frac{1+x}{1-x}$ yields $$I=2\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\ln^2(u)}}{(u+1)^2}du$$
But I don't know if this form is any easier to tackle.
Any idea?

Getting rid of the logarithm via $v=\log u$ leads to$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{2e^{-v^2+v}}{(e^v+1)^2},dv$$which may be doable with residue calculus.

Does this answer your question? The integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-x^2}}{(1+e^x)^2} dx$. - substituting $v=\frac12\log u$ leads to a component of the linked integral $T(2)$. No closed form was given though

Your integral is related to what are known as Mordell integrals. This old question of mine is related.

I continue from @user170231's comment (dated Apr 3, 2024).
We have
$$
I
{=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{2e^{-v^2+v}}{(e^v+1)^2}dv
\\=
\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{2e^{-v^2+v}}{(e^v+1)^2}dv
+
\int_{0}^\infty \frac{2e^{-v^2+v}}{(e^v+1)^2}dv
\\=
\int_{0}^\infty \frac{2e^{-v^2-v}}{(e^{-v}+1)^2}dv
+
\int_{0}^\infty \frac{2e^{-v^2+v}}{(e^v+1)^2}dv
\\=
4\int_{0}^\infty \frac{e^{-v^2-v}}{(e^{-v}+1)^2}dv
\\=
4\int_{0}^\infty e^{-v^2-v}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)(-1)^ne^{-nv}dv
\\=
4\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)(-1)^n\int_{0}^\infty e^{-v^2-(n+1)v}dv
\\=
4\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)(-1)^n\int_{0}^\infty e^{-v^2-(n+1)v-\frac{(n+1)^2}{4}}e^{\frac{(n+1)^2}{4}}dv
\\=
4\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)(-1)^ne^{\frac{(n+1)^2}{4}}\int_{\frac{n+1}{2}}^\infty e^{-v^2}dv
\\=
2\sqrt\pi\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)(-1)^ne^{\frac{(n+1)^2}{4}}\text{erfc}\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right),
}
$$
where $\text{erfc}\left(\cdot\right)$ is the complementary error function.
